# Nodejs docxtemplater hide images based on tag

Tags: node.js, docxtemplater

I know you can add images to the document with the image module (or the free one) to the document but is it also possible somehow to hide an image in the document based on a tag value?

I have three images on my template document and I want to hide an image if the tag of the image is set to false like my template gets this informations:

```
{
    "hasImage1": false,
    "hasImage2": true,
    "hasImage3": false
}
```

and with that I only want to show the image 2 in my document. Since those are free floating images I can't wrap them around `{#hasImage1} img {/hasImage1}`. I also tryed to just add this syntax to the image alt text like you would replace the image but with no success.

The other way around, adding the image, would also be a problem since I can't just put an tag where the image should be because it is a free floating one.

Any idea if this is even possible?

Comment: Hello ! Edgar  here, the creator of docxtemplater. I don't know about the open-source version, but the paid version of the image module allows to remove an image when you set the alt-text to "{hasImage}". if hasImage returns true, the image is kept, if it returns false, the image is removed.